# Why does the java.lang.reflect.WildcardType class return arrays for the upper and lower bounds?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Recently, I've read a lot about Java Generics since I'm going to start a project which heavily depends on those mechanics and the public reflection API allowing accessing them. But in my understanding, those are a bit contradicting:

> Note, a wildcard can have only one bound. In can neither have both an upper and a lower bound nor several upper or lower bounds.  Constructs such as " ? super Long extends Number "  or  " ? extends Comparable & Cloneable " are illegal.

(http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ102; section Wildcard Bounds)

Thus, a wildcard always has only one bound (if you ignore the upper bound "Object" that goes with every lower bound wildcard). But if you look at the corresponding reflection API class [`WildcardType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/WildcardType.html), it seems like that this is not the whole truth:

Why does the API only provide the functions `getLowerBounds()` and `getUpperBounds()` and why do they return an array? Is there any scenario, in which an array with a length of at least two will be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources I currently have available (1.8.0_172) contain this "internal" comment:

```
// one or many? Up to language spec; currently only one, but this API
// allows for generalization.
```

Thus it seems as if the API is designed for the case that multiple bounds might be allowed in the future.

**Edit:**

[Here's a link to the 1.8.0_181 sources](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/lang/reflect/wildcardtype.java), which shows that this comment is still present. ([Here's the same link for OpenJDK 10.0.2](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/lang/reflect/wildcardtype.java))

Why this generalization even if it isn't needed? Assume you'd later change the api and all the existing code would need to be changed from `Type` to `Type[]` our you'd need to add new methods making it hard to explain why there are two methods.